# Access connection event in MS FTP service using Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, ftp

I'm monitoring a directory for FTP uploads on the server using a CF event gateway. Fine so far, but I want to get at the IP address of the computer uploading the file. The server is Windows Web Server 2008 R2 IIS 7 and Windows FTP 7.5

What I am aiming for is growl type message if the uploaded file has been handled correctly (or else error msg) and for that I need the IP of the sender. (there is no problem with NAT within the LAN)

The FTP service writes a log containing the IP which I could try to correlate with the directory monitoring event, but other than by scraping the log is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ColdFusion has no connection to the FTP service in IIS, you'll have to handle this through the logs. You can, however, use something like LogParser (see [this article](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2007/12/20/Parsing-an-IIS-log-file-in-ColdFusion)
from Ray Camden on how to use it to parse an IIS log file.

Good luck!

Dan